# Android Log - causing application crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

Well I am working on an android application, to upload photos on FTP server. The application was working fine, I tried to modify the code and get the user data in log file using **Log.v**.

Now here my problems starts, each and every time I tries to run my application it crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("userData",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UserInfo(firstname VARCHAR,lastname VARCHAR);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES('pulkit','gupta');");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM UserInfo",null);
        //Log.d("result",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
        db.close();

    }
```

**attaching my log image ..**

```
12-09 07:23:19.825: E/Trace(1942): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-09 07:23:21.165: D/AndroidRuntime(1942): Shutting down VM
12-09 07:23:21.165: W/dalvikvm(1942): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abc.photoapp/abc.photoapp.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 12
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 12
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at abc.photoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-09 07:23:21.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     ... 11 more
```

**My AVD Configurations**

**Device: 4.0" WVGA (480x800 hdpi)
Target: Android 4.2.2 – API Level 17
CPU/ABI: ARM (armabi-v7a)
RAM 512**

**can any one help me out the solution of my problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot cursor.moveToFirst() try it

Comment: thanks for your Answer..but I don't think **Cursor.movetofirst() is a pre-defined function** ... Can you please elaborate it little further.

Comment: try curcor.moveToFirst()